# Consider the following set F of functional dependencies on the relation schema r(A,B,C,D,E,F):

Tags: functional-dependencies, database-theory

I have tried to reach out to my instructor with no luck and I really want to understand this process, but no matter how much I read the material I cannot seem to make this fit in my little brain. Can someone please help me with the following questions?

```
A-->BCD
BC-->DE
B-->D
D-->A
```

> a. Compute B+.

I believe that this one is as follows. Does this seem to be correct?

B+ denotes closure of B.
B --> D
B+ = {BD}
D --> A
B+ = {ABD}
A --> BCD
B+ = {ABCD}
BC --> DE
B+ = {ABCDE}

All the attributes of the relation can be found by B. So, B is the primary key of the relation.

> b. Prove (using Armstrong’s axioms) that AF is a superkey.

I do not understand what to do with F, because it does not show up in the above relationships.

> c. Compute a canonical cover for the above set of functional dependencies F; give each step of your derivation with an explanation.
>
> d. Give a 3NF decomposition of r based on the canonical cover.

Answer (score 1):

> All the attributes of the relation can
>   be found by B. So, B is the primary
>   key of the relation.

No. If B could determine all the attributes of the relation, B would be a candidate key. There might be more than one candidate key, and there's no formal reason to identify one candidate key as "primary" and others as "secondary".

But B doesn't determine all the attributes of the relation. It doesn't determine F.

> I do not understand what to do with F,
>   because it does not show up in the
>   above relationships.

Speaking informally, if an attribute doesn't show up on the right-hand side of any functional dependencies, it has to be a part of every superkey.

```
r = {ABCDEF}
```

To prove that AF is a superkey (or candidate key), compute the closure of AF for the relation R = {ABCDEF}. Use the same FDs above.

Comment: Since the closure of AF gives all the possible attributes, is this sufficient proof that AF is a superkey ? @MikeSherrill'Cat Recall'

Comment: @Jarvis: Loosely speaking, that's pretty much the definition of *superkey*. A superkey uniquely identifies a tuple. So every superkey will "give all the possible attributes", in the sense that the superkey functionally determines all attributes that aren't part of the superkey.

Answer (score 1):

**Part C:** canonical cover

```
A->BCD, BC->DE, B->D, D->A
```

1. Remove D from BC->DE

   A->BCD, BC->E, B->D, D->A
2. Remove D from A->BCD

   A->BC, BC->E, B->D, D->A
3. Decompose A->BC

   A->B, A->C, BC->E, B->D, D->A
4. Remove C from BC->E

   ? : **B->D->A->C** => **B->C** => **B->BC->E** => **B->E**
   ? : B+:: B->BD->ABD->ABCD->ABCDE (E is an element of B+)
   A->B, A->C, B->E, B->D, D->A

Answer (score 0):

## 1 reducing each FD to single att on right:

A->B A->C A-D BC -> D BC -> E B->D D->A

## 2 removing extraneous atts:

BC -> D is reduced to B->D and BC -> E is reduced to B->E since C is extraneous in both.

## 3 removing redundant FDs:

A->B, A->C, B->D, B->E, D->A

Somebody pl correct my answer if I'm wrong.

Comment: STEP 2 : How C is extraneous in BC->E ? How B will determine E i.e B->E does not exist.